# html textfield in WebView in an Android application is hidden by the soft keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, webview, textfield

I have an Android application that is a TabHost with a WebView. I use it to load a specific html file that has a text field in its bottom part.

When I touch the html textfield, the soft keyboard pops up, and hides the textfield, so that I cannot see what I have typed.

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <TabWidget
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="63dp" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>      
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I have tried to configure the AndroidManifest.xml file with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` with no success. I have also tried replacing the `FrameLayout` in my layout with `ScollView`, but that caused my `webview` to increase in size indefinitely when the application is running.. this may be due to some javascript I have running on the page.

I have noticed that the android's web browser has a nifty behavior - in a web page, after the soft keyboard pops up, the web page scrolls smoothly so that the focusable textfield is visible to the user. How can I have this kind of behavior in my application?

Comment: A way to get around this issue may be get notified when the soft keybaord appears, and then resize manually the webview. 
I have tried implementing onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo) in all my layout classes, but could not get a notification when the keyboard appears.

Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue. (about a week after I posted the question; I only got to answering in stackoverflow today...)

I had pieces in my code that changed the WebView's height (to have room for a TabBar). Turns out that when you invoke setLayoutParams on a WebView, it will no longer change its height even if you have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` set.

I circumvented the need to change the WebView's height by adding the TabBar to the main.xml layout file, with an initial size of 0. When I increase the TabBar's size, the WebView's size decreases automatically, and it preserves the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` behavior.

Comment: Do know whether this is a known bug of the WebView? Just stumbled across the same problem

Comment: I did not file a bug for this issue back in the day. Back then the Android API version I was working on was 1.6, or 2.2 (I can't remember)

Comment: I had a more complex layout, so a fix was harder, but in the end I did the same as you did and circumvented to call setLayoutParams with a fixed height for the webView

Comment: Can you show the code how you did the `setLayoutParams()` with your webview. I am really stuck at this very problem and is unable to find a solution yet. Please update your answer.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting crazy nothing works `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` may help but be sure to have your app not in full screen.

Removing full screen for my app solved the problem with the layout resize with softkeyboard.

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
```

Comment: Note that `adjustResize` will not work if `windowFullscreen` is set to `true`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what he said.